# Select only changes to a value from an audit log table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, audit-tables

In MS SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a table Foo, and for every insert and update on Foo, I also insert into FooAuditLog the date, user, the PK FooId and a few of the other columns of Foo, including one numeric value, call it cxp.

I now need to retrieve the history of changes to cxp over time for a given FooId.  But it is possible to save a Foo without changing cxp, and I need to ignore those values.

For example, if the Audit Log entries for a specific Foo (ie `select date, user, cxp from FooAuditLog where fooId=17`) look like this:

```
Date      User     Cxp
-------------------------
10/26     Fred     42
10/28     George   38
11/7      Tom      38
11/9      Fred     38
11/12     Joe      33
11/14     Tom      33
11/18     George   38
```

Then I need to modify the query to return only:

```
Date      User     Cxp
-----------------------------
10/26     Fred     42
10/28     George   38
11/12     Joe      33
11/18     George   38
```

And ignore the entries on 11/7, 11/9, and 11/14.   I had considered a `select distinct (cpx) ... group by date` but I do need to capture the entry where the value changes back to a previous value.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What is your logic behind ignoring `11/7, 11/9, and 11/14`?.

Comment: @Kaf: I want to only select log entries where the desired value (cxp) has changed.  On the dates mentioned, the cxp is the same as it was on the last save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the previous value.  This version uses MySQL syntax with a correlated subquery to get the result:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select cxp from t t2 where t2.date < t.date order by date desc limit1
             ) as prevcxp
      from t
     ) t
where prevcxp is NULL or prevcxp <> cxp
```

In other databases, you might use `lag()` instead of the subquery, the `limit` might be replaced by a `top` or even `fetch first 1 row`.